# Event synchronization issue in an Android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Here is an issue I am facing in an `Android` app.
Please let me know if I need to give more information.

There is an animation running inside the app.
And while it is running I can push a button which causes the following chunk of code to be executed:

```
......
randomNumber?.also {
    it.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0xFF,0x00,0x00))
}

btnLabel.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0xFF,0x00,0x00))
missCount += 1
setFixIndication()
......
```

Finally, this is the problem puzzling me.

The lines of the code containing *.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0xFF,0x00,0x00))* are executed as soon as the button is touched, without waiting the end of the animation. This is what I expect.

But the code inside the called function *setFixIndication()* is only executed after the animation is over. This is not what I want.

In case this may be useful, I can say that the *setFixIndication()* function is just changing the position of some view in the layout.

Does anyone has a tip on how to handle the problem or where to look at?

Just in case this may be useful here is the code for the *setFixIndication()* function:

```
   fun setFixIndication() {
        if (fixPanel == null) {
            fixPanel = ImageView(this)
            fixPanel?.id = View.generateViewId()
            fixPanel?.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_2p_fix)
            fixPanel?.elevation = (-1).dpToPixels(this)
            constraintLayout?.addView(fixPanel)
        }

        val constrSet = ConstraintSet()
        val anchor = 38
        val shift = 180
        constrSet.clone(constraintLayout)

        val btnIdx = get2Expo(randomNumber?.text.toString())
        val btnID = resources.getIdentifier('N'.plus(btnIdx.toString()),"id",packageName)
        val shfMult = 3 - (btnIdx - btnIdx % 8) / 8

        fixPanel?.also {
            constrSet.connect(it.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT, btnID, ConstraintSet.LEFT)
            constrSet.connect(it.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, btnID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT)
            constrSet.connect(it.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, btnID, ConstraintSet.TOP)
            constrSet.connect(it.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, btnID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
            constrSet.setMargin(it.id, ConstraintSet.TOP,anchor-shift*shfMult)
        }
        constrSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)
    }
```

Here is one more thing I noticed. If instead of using *setFixIndication()* I use another function *setFixShortIndic()* like the following one:

```
fun setFixShortIndic() {
    val btnIdx = get2Expo(randomNumber?.text.toString())
    val btnLabel = findViewById<TextView>(exponArray[btnIdx])
    btnLabel.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0x99,0xFF,0x00))
}
```

This last function only changes the text color of a label.

Then my problem disappears and the *setFixShortIndic()* function executes without waiting for the end of the animation.

This proves that the issue is connected to something I do inside the *setFixIndication()* function.

That said I still do not know how to solve the problem.

Comment: You should post `setFixIndication()`'s definition.

Comment: @Praveen. I just added the code for the function in the post. Please take a look.